# @media width doesn't fill full page, what I am doing wrong?

Tags: html, css, media

I want to make an 100% full page, within 4 images on each row. But if you resize the window you'll get 3 images than 2 images till there is 1 left. After research I become at @media to fill the full page without getting any blank spaces. Now i've made this jsfiddle but if you resize the results window you will see blank spaces who are not filled. What am I doing wrong?

```
@media only screen and (min-width : 354px) {
 /* Smartphone view: 1 tile */
.image{
   width: 100% }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8hfLkb3k/

The image always must fill both width's, if the width is 50% for 2 both images must fill it in for 50%.

Thanks.

Comment: can you explain little more clear of what exactly you want the output to be ...if you can add some screenshots would be more helpful

Comment: I think it's working as it should be. Your div with .image class is adjusting it's width accordingly. The actual image inside of the div is not filling it from edge to edge. Is that the problem?

Comment: Look at this jsfiddle I made, if you resize the results box you will see that the images always fill full width. No clear spaces. But the images are not filling the div full. I want that every image fills the div 100%. And with no clear spaces if you resize the window.


Is this good enough?

Comment: Forgot the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hw8swcpm/

Answer (score 1):

Your images (`<img>` elements) are not expanding to the full width of the `.image` containers because you're missing this rule, which you can add to your CSS:

```
.image img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

---

Here's your example code updated to show this working:

```css
.image img {
  width: 100%;
}
.f_left {
  float: left;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 354px) {
  /* Smartphone view: 1 tile */
  .image {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 708px) {
  /* Smartphone view: 2 tile */
  .image {
    width: 50%;
  }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1062px) {
  /* Small desktop / ipad view: 3 tiles */
  .image {
    width: 33.3%;
  }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1417px) {
  /* Medium desktop: 4 tiles */
  .image {
    width: 25%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="image f_left">
  <img src="http://www.devual.nl/project/gmsbase/img/cover.png" />
</div>
<div class="image f_left">
  <img src="http://www.devual.nl/project/gmsbase/img/cover.png" />
</div>
<div class="image f_left">
  <img src="http://www.devual.nl/project/gmsbase/img/cover.png" />
</div>
<div class="image f_left">
  <img src="http://www.devual.nl/project/gmsbase/img/cover.png" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! This is what I'm looking for, do you also know how I can fit all it with a max-height? Because know all the images will to big so the resolution of the images will be bad.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using max-widths for your media queries, but you don't have to do this, as long as what you do gives you the intended and correct result.

In my working example I've chosen to set the one-image container for 25% unless something changes like the viewport width.

At 1024, 767 and 600 I've chosen the 1/3 and 1/2 sizes and finally the 100% width.

I expect this is what you mean, but feel free to adapt this code as you see fit, especially to match the media query viewport attributes to what you desire.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.one-image {
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.one-image img {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  display: block;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1068px) {
  .one-image {
    width: 33.33%;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .one-image {
    width: 50%;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .one-image {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="one-image">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200">
</div>
<div class="one-image">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200">
</div>
<div class="one-image">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200">
</div>
<div class="one-image">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200">
</div>
```